# how to tint/highlight qpixmap only the area that has non-zero alpha

Tags: qt, qpainter

I have a QPixmap that has some transparent area. What can I do to apply a highlight/tint to only area that has non-zero alpha?

This is what I have right now, which tints the whole image.

```
QPixmap highlighedPixmap = myPixmap;
QPainter pixmapPainter;
pixmapPainter.begin(&highlighedPixmap);
pixmapPainter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_ColorDodge);
pixmapPainter.fillRect(highlighedPixmap.rect(), QColor(180, 180, 180, 100));
pixmapPainter.end();
```

input image:

[image]

expected result image:

[image]

Comment: I'm might be missing the point slightly but... I think you want to paint `highlighedPixmap` *over* a solid coloured background.

Comment: @G.M. hmm, I don't think I get what you mean. So `myPixmap` is my original image and I want to add a tint/highlight to that image but leave the transparent area still transparent. The way I did would tint the transparent as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right option is `CompositionMode_SourceAtop`:

```
QPixmap highlighedPixmap = myPixmap;
QPainter pixmapPainter(&highlighedPixmap);
pixmapPainter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceAtop);
pixmapPainter.fillRect(highlighedPixmap.rect(), foregroundColor);
pixmapPainter.end();
```

Within Qt directory in *...\examples\widgets\painting\composition*, there is a "Composition Modes" tool, which lets you experiment with all composition modes. I found it in Qt 5.2.1 but it should be there at least since Qt 4.8.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it didn't work in my case. Using CompositionMode_SourceIn completely covers my original image with the foregroundColor. I want some sort of blending instead. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: `CompositionMode_SourceOver` may be your choice then, but it would be better if you can supply input and output example images.

Comment: `CompositionMode_SourceOver` did blend the image with the foregroundColor but it also tinted the transparent area of the original image. Is there way to leave the transparent part of the original image unchanged? I added example images to the question.

Comment: OK, the right option should be `CompositionMode_SourceAtop`. You can find, within your Qt directory in `...\examples\widgets\painting\composition`, the "Composition Modes" tool, which lets you experiment with all composition modes. I found it in Qt 5.2.1 but it should be there at least since Qt 4.8.

Comment: Thanks @mbjoe. That worked out great. Could you update your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Edited the answer changing `CompositionMode_SourceIn` into `CompositionMode_SourceAtop`.